# How can I get programatically any single Log generated by my App?

Tags: java, android, logging, logcat

Any Android App produces Logs in the LogCat, even those not generated by developer's source code via `Log.d`, `Log.i`, `Log.w` and `Log.e` etc. etc. etc.. Perhaps Google Developers has some "automagic" thing for this, I don't know about that...

The point is I remember, years ago, **I could somehow extend the class `Application`**, override one or several of it's methods, and then:

- Add my own code to process any single `Log` object generated by my
  App in the LogCat
- **Do whatever I wanted with them** (getting the label and the description strings, and then send them via mail, Slack etc., basically)
- And then, calling `super` on that method and let the system do with that Log whatever `Application` by default does with it...

**or something like that**... if I recall correctly, I could do this with any log in my app's namespace. Or maybe it was just the crash handler? I can't remember...

It's been so long since I accomplished that (several years already!), so I don't remember how could I do that anymore... I search the internet like crazy trying to recall, but I am struggling to find it again... :-S

```
// ...public?? oO
[¿¿??] class MyApp extends Application [...] {
// [...]

    @Override
    public void whateverMethodItWasIDontRemember(params) {
        // My coding stuff for the error reports
        /* magic :D */
        sendTheLogsMyWay();

        // I bet this is important
        super.whateverMethodItWasIDontRemember(params);
    }

    // [...]
}
```

---

I am about to launch the first Beta version of a new app, so I want beta testers to have a reliable way to send me LogCat's feed if anything has to be reported due to crashes, unexpected behaviour etc.

---

I mean, it would be ridiculous having to fill with `CustomLog`s every inch of source code for the beta version, when, **in most cases, default logs are more than enough** to see why it crashed (errors), or what optimization problems (usually warnings) might the Beta Tester have... not to mention that, if I forget to monitor something this way, the ridiculously big effort to log every single line of my code would be useless... oO

```
// -__- Mmm... perhaps extending Log itself
//        would be more elegant... 
import android.util.Log

public final class CustomLog {
    public static void d(String label, String msg) {
        // AKA My code to handle it
        packItForNextErrorReport(label, msg);

        Log.d(label, msg);
    }

    /*
      * ... and so on with Log.i, w and e.
      *    ...I think you get the idea
      */
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you were thinking of [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra) documentation [here](https://www.acra.ch/docs/Setup)

Comment: I am not sure... perhaps, but I don't remember using other libraries than the ones for HTTP calls, or mail sendings or things like that... perhaps I don't remember some library I needed, perhaps I didn't need more than extending `Application` and override some method... but I did make it work via Slack, that's for sure